# Problems loading .class file with getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java

I'm using Eclipse as IDE. I've imported a .class file from a folder and I'm trying to use getResourceAsStream() to load it and then define it as a class. But it won't work, it comes up as null.

I've placed it in a folder called resources. So I'm using the path "/resources/Test.class"

I've tried loading a .txt file and that work. However it doesn't seem to want to load my .class file since it just ends up being null .

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Solved: Sorry I'm a bit fresh to Java and this IDE so it was a bit of a mixup. The way I called the function, it expected the file to be in the same exact folder as the class that was calling it. Importing it into my package, solved the issue.

Sorry for not thinking ahead a bit further before posting. Thanks to those who took their time though!

Comment: You'll get better help faster if you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Give us some code (as little as possible), which we can run to duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those are some of the things that usually work. If they don't, please post a minimal test case for us to reproduce your issue.

Try `ThisClassName.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.

Also, if the path is in your classpath, try just "Test.class" without the folder name.

Comment: I added code and some further explanation, I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit fresh to Java and this IDE so it was a bit of a mixup. The way I called the function, it expected the file to be in the same exact folder as the class that was calling it. Importing it into my package, solved the issue. 

Sorry for not thinking ahead a bit further before posting. Thanks to those who took their time though!